# mozilla webxr-viewer remote debug on non-jailbroken ios

Tags: ios, remote-debugging, mozilla, webxr

[webxr viewer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/webxr-viewer/id1295998056) is an webxr-enabled browser for ios.

works great so far, but now i am at a point where i need to debug my scenes.

i can connect the phone to a mac and debug safari,
is there a way to get that same functionality for the webxr-viewer app?

the viewer itself has a "webxr debug" button, so i guess the developers thought about this possibility, but no documentation ever mentions how to actually connect to a debug ui/app on the mac.

1. am i right in assuming i would have to download the webxr branch from [the firefox-ios github](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/tree/webxr) and build it myself?
2. is there a way to debug arkit directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theoretically, one could do as i write above,
clone the webxr branch of firefox-ios, then build it in xcode and install it via usb on the phone.
i started doing so, until i clicked the build button:
this needs a developer account with apple to work.

since i do not know if building firefox-ios would allow me to debug the arkit scene, i decided not to bother.

i instead opted to solving this using a classical ie6-style debugDiv:

```
const debugDiv = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(debugDiv)
try {
  // ... code that errors
} catch(e) {
  debugDiv.innerHTML += e.toString()
}
```

this needs to be done inside the arkit executed code, since arkit adds a weird sandbox, also requires the "dom-overlay" feature in webxr to be requested and available, but if those two prerequisites are met, it works like it's 2001...